# Why should this formula be true?

Tags: integration

I was just studying Fubini's theorem the other day, and the statement is that if $f(x,y)$ is in $L^{1}(\mu \times \nu)$ then the following integrals are equal:
$$ \iint _{X \times Y} f(x,y) d(\mu \times \nu)$$
$$ \int _{X}  \int _{Y} f(x,y) d \mu  d \nu $$
$$ \int _{Y}  \int _{X} f(x,y) d \nu  d \mu $$

Ok, I understand why this would be true for a continuous function. Of course if you slice a bread one way for Konstantin, and then the other way for Svetlana, you still get the same amount between them. I don't understand why this is true for bread with countable discontinuities or without compact support. I guess I don't need to worry about this too much, because all the functions in physics and engineering are continuous, but it still there are applications to finance which need the full power of this theorem.

Comment: Have you tried reading a proof?

Comment: Yes, I have read proof in book by Sergei Ovchinnikov, but I am looking for intuitive explanation.

Comment: If the function is integrable, then you can decompose it as sums of a continuous one plus another of very small area.

Comment: "Intuitive" explanations in measure theory usually come from Littlewood's three principles.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littlewood's_three_principles_of_real_analysis

Comment: It is quite not true that all functions in physics and engineering are continuous...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez No, but all the functions in engineering have a Taylor series that truncates exactly after the linear term ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an intuitive reason; integrable functions behave a lot like simple functions, by definition of Lebesgue integral (I.e. they are within $\epsilon$). Simple functions are like characterisitic functions. So basically, ask yourself if measuring a measurable set one way is different than another. And to answer that, realize that measurable sets have measure equal to their outer measure, which is based off of open sets. And open sets are unions of balls.

So, because it's true for a ball, it's true for all integrable functions.

This argument is within $\epsilon$ of being rigorous for some $\epsilon$.